# read a file contains list and comma separation in python

Tags: python

I have a file(.txt) which contains: `[0 1,1 1,3 2,4 1]`

I want to read the file in this way:

```
0 1 /n
1 1 /n
3 2 /n
4 1 /n
```

I have problem how to eliminate brackets and separate each line by comma. 
Thanks for your suggestions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A different method that will also work if the brackets are not the first and the last character:

```
print s[s.index("[")+1:s.index("]")].replace(",", "\n")
```

If the brackets always *are* the ifrst and the last character of the string, you can simplify this to

```
print s[1:-1].replace(",", "\n")
```

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> s = "[0 1,1 1,3 2,4 1]"
>>> print '\n'.join(s[1:-1].split(','))
0 1
1 1
3 2
4 1
```

Comment: Slick, but doesn't validate much. In particular, it gives the same result for the following: `{0 1,1 1,3 2,4 1}`, `(0 1,1 1,3 2,4 1)`, which might be acceptable, but this might not: `00 1,1 1,3 2,4 10`. Depending on the application, a more elaborate solution might help out.

Answer (score 0):

Simple snippet:

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as _f:
    myfile = _f.readlines()

myline = myfile[0]

print '\n'.join(myline[1:-1].split(','))
```

If you have several similar lines on your file, on can iterate with a for statement on 'myfile'.

```
for line in myfile:
    print '\n'.join(line[1:-1].split(','))
```

Note, if you are sure that brackets are on beginning and end of the line, you can use :

```
print "\n".join(line.strip('[]').split(','))
```